# Difference between travel and travelling

Tags: difference

In the following two sentences which one is more appropriate

> The B109 funds are intended to offset the loss of wages due to TB, and to help with **(both travelling and nutrition)**
>
> The B109 funds are intended to offset the loss of wages due to TB, and to help with **(both travel and nutrition)**

**Travel** and **traveling** both are noun and refer to the activity of travelling so I don't see any deiiference

Answer (score 2):

"travel" and "travelling" are similar, but they are not quite the same:

- "travelling" is the present participle form of the (intransitive) verb "to travel", which refers to the act of moving oneself from one place to another (usually in the sense of going to another city/country/etc).  You can think of "travelling" as basically "going on a journey".
- "travel", as a noun, refers to the movement itself of something or someone from one place to another.

That is, "travelling" is an activity that people do, while "travel" is something that happens to people.  Another way to look at this is that "travel" is the result of "travelling".

Given that "travelling" and "travel" are usually pretty closely tied (when one happens, the other happens), the two can sometimes be used somewhat interchangeably.  One difference, though, is that "travelling" usually implies a specific person (or people) going to a specific destination, while "travel" just describes movement in general.

For this reason, when we are talking about overall concepts of many people going different places (for example, "air travel", or "business travel"), we usually talk about the resulting movement ("travel"), not the (individual) activity of going to a particular place ("travelling").  Talking about the activity generally implies you're referring more to a specific instance or a specific person travelling somewhere.

So in the case of your example, either form could technically be used, but since the context seems to be talking more about "people going places in general" and not "a specific trip" or "a specific person's activity", then in this case I think "travel" is probably the more appropriate word.

Answer (score 0):

To start, heres a good reference: [wordhippo.com Noun Travel](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/travel.html)

Because:

> The noun travel can be countable or uncountable.

It can be Plural and Non Plural.

**Travelling is also Countable and Uncountable in a Plural sense** > Meaning it can be used to reference One person travelling, while also **being used as "Travellings" to describe multiple people travelling.**

So you can use Travel or Travelling for your context of sentence.

Comment: One can use "travels", as in the classic title  *Travels with Charlie*, but "Travelings" is at best very unusual. In fact i don't recall ever encountering that form.n any case the choice between "travel" and "traveling" does not have to do with whether it is a countable noun, nor with plural vs singular. "Travels" is not used to describe a trip by multiple people, but to describe multiple trips.